# Cannot Deserialize XML file

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I have a problem making my program deserialize a XML file.
For this, I have looked at several solutions, like [This Deserializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tz8csy73%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).
But Even if I try to copy/paste that example, it will still not give me anything. It doesnt throw an error or anything, just gives me nothing.

My XML looks like;

```
<PRODUCTS>
<PRODUCT>
<PRODUCT_ID>120129</PRODUCT_ID>
<TITLE_DK><![CDATA[Udlejning - Pioneer CDJ-1000 MK3]]></TITLE_DK>
<STATUS>1</STATUS>
<STOCK>99</STOCK>
<DISABLE_ON_EMPTY>1</DISABLE_ON_EMPTY>
<MANUFACTURER_ID>0</MANUFACTURER_ID>
<DELIVERY_ID>standard</DELIVERY_ID>
<FREIGHT_ID></FREIGHT_ID>
<UNIT_ID>1</UNIT_ID>
<NUMBER><![CDATA[0]]></NUMBER>
<EAN></EAN>
<PRODUCT_LINK><![CDATA[]]></PRODUCT_LINK>
<URL><![CDATA[/produkter/4977---aarhus--/120129-udlejning---pioneer-cdj-1000-mk3/]]></URL>
<WEIGHT>0,00</WEIGHT>
<FOCUS_FRONTPAGE>0</FOCUS_FRONTPAGE>
<FOCUS_CART>0</FOCUS_CART>
<SORTING>0</SORTING>
<LANGUAGE_LAYERS></LANGUAGE_LAYERS>
<USER_ACCESS></USER_ACCESS>
<USERGROUP_ACCESS></USERGROUP_ACCESS>
<RELATED_PRODUCT_IDS></RELATED_PRODUCT_IDS>
<RELATED_PRODUCT_NUMBERS></RELATED_PRODUCT_NUMBERS>
<PDF_FILES></PDF_FILES>
<DATE_ADDED>0000-00-00 00:00:00</DATE_ADDED>
<DATE_UPDATED>2014-01-08 12:48:58</DATE_UPDATED>
<EDBPRISER_ID></EDBPRISER_ID>
<DELETE></DELETE>
<DESCRIPTION_LIST_DK><![CDATA[Pris pr døgn 400,-]]></DESCRIPTION_LIST_DK>
<DESCRIPTION_LONG_DK><></DESCRIPTION_LONG_DK>
<DESCRIPTION_SHORT_DK><></DESCRIPTION_SHORT_DK>
<CATEGORY_ID>4977</CATEGORY_ID>
<SUB_CATEGORY_ID>4967</SUB_CATEGORY_ID>
<LIST_PRICE>0,00</LIST_PRICE>
<BUY_PRICE>300,00</BUY_PRICE>
<MIN_AMOUNT>1</MIN_AMOUNT>
<PRICE>300,00</PRICE>
<DISCOUNT>0,00</DISCOUNT>
<DISCOUNT_TYPE>a</DISCOUNT_TYPE>
<DISCOUNT_GROUP>0</DISCOUNT_GROUP>
<PICTURE_FOLDER></PICTURE_FOLDER>
<VARIANT_ID></VARIANT_ID>
<VARIANT_TYPES></VARIANT_TYPES>
</PRODUCT>
.....
```

And my object class

```
public class PRODUCTS
{
    private List<PRODUCT> _product;
    public PRODUCTS()
    {
        _product = new List<PRODUCT>();
    }

    public List<PRODUCT> AllProducts
    {
        get { return _product; }
        set { _product = value; }
    }

    [XmlRoot]
    public class PRODUCT
    {

        public PRODUCT()
        {

        }

        public uint PRODUCT_ID { get; set; }

        public string TITLE_DK { get; set; }

        public byte STATUS { get; set; }

        public ushort STOCK { get; set; }

        public byte DISABLE_ON_EMPTY { get; set; }

        public byte MANUFACTURER_ID { get; set; }

        public string DELIVERY_ID { get; set; }

        public object FREIGHT_ID { get; set; }

        public byte UNIT_ID { get; set; }

        public string NUMBER { get; set; }

        public object EAN { get; set; }

        public string PRODUCT_LINK { get; set; }

        public string URL { get; set; }

        public string WEIGHT { get; set; }

        public byte FOCUS_FRONTPAGE { get; set; }

        public byte FOCUS_CART { get; set; }

        public byte SORTING { get; set; }

        public object LANGUAGE_LAYERS { get; set; }

        public object USER_ACCESS { get; set; }

        public object USERGROUP_ACCESS { get; set; }

        public object RELATED_PRODUCT_IDS { get; set; }

        public object RELATED_PRODUCT_NUMBERS { get; set; }

        public object PDF_FILES { get; set; }

        public string DATE_ADDED { get; set; }

        public string DATE_UPDATED { get; set; }

        public object EDBPRISER_ID { get; set; }

        public object DELETE { get; set; }

        public string DESCRIPTION_LIST_DK { get; set; }

        public string DESCRIPTION_LONG_DK { get; set; }

        public string DESCRIPTION_SHORT_DK { get; set; }

        public ushort CATEGORY_ID { get; set; }

        public string SUB_CATEGORY_ID { get; set; }

        public string LIST_PRICE { get; set; }

        public string BUY_PRICE { get; set; }

        public byte MIN_AMOUNT { get; set; }

        public string PRICE { get; set; }

        public string DISCOUNT { get; set; }

        public string DISCOUNT_TYPE { get; set; }

        public byte DISCOUNT_GROUP { get; set; }

        public string PICTURES { get; set; }

        public string URL_PICTURE { get; set; }

        public object PICTURE_FOLDER { get; set; }

        public object VARIANT_ID { get; set; }

        public object VARIANT_TYPES { get; set; }

    }
```

And the method for deserialization is :

```
        private PRODUCTS DeserializeObject(string filename)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Reading with XmlReader");

        XmlSerializer serializer = new
            XmlSerializer(typeof(PRODUCTS));

        FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open);
        XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(fs);

        PRODUCTS products;

        products = (PRODUCTS)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        fs.Close();
        return products;
    }
```

But this gives me nothing - I dont even think it runs through the whole thing (?)

The same was with the example from [This page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tz8csy73%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Didnt give me anything as well

Comment: I'm not sure but the content <![CDATA[]]> generates an invalid xml file.

Comment: Usually there's just a slight mismatch in the XML and your data object model. Sometimes the easiest is to instead create a sample/dummy instance of `PRODUCTS` populated with some simple test data and serialize it out to an XML file. Then compare what your .NET object expects to read, and what you're trying to feed it.

Comment: Also, I _think_ the empty `CDATA` field is technically valid, but these entries: `<DESCRIPTION_LONG_DK><></DESCRIPTION_LONG_DK>
<DESCRIPTION_SHORT_DK><></DESCRIPTION_SHORT_DK>` I'm almost _certain_ are _not_ valid. (notice the empty tags)

Comment: So I should not try to deserialize the empty tags ?
It would take a lot of time to remove all those tags. I got this .xml file from a customer, where I have to deserialize. And this file is large! In my code, I have also tried to make them nullable (those with empty tags), to see if that could help. But I still get nothing. And it will take a long time to modify each and every product element in the xml file to make it look properly.

Comment: @MothCreek: You might be able to pre-sanitize the XML by removing the empty tags: first read the file data as a string, then run a `String.Replace("<>", "")` call to remove any instances of those empty arrows. I'd suggest informing your customer that the XML is invalid and to fix it on their side, but I know that's probably not gonna happen. Hopefully this is the fix you need (aside from minor formatting issues)!